# Fluentd container not running on Openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, dockerfile, fluentd

I am trying to run the fluentd image on Openshift. I am using the official image of Fluentd from Docker Hub for the same.

However, i get the following error -

```
adduser: permission denied (are you root?)
chown: unknown user fluent
chown: unknown user fluent
su-exec: setgroups(0): Operation not permitted
```

I think this is because the Fluentd container wants to run as root, while Openshift doesn't allow containers that want to run as root.

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem? Run the Fluentd container as a non-root user? Thanks in advance for any help.

The URL of the repo is - https://hub.docker.com/r/fluent/fluentd/

Comment: What is the URL for the Git repo and Dockerfile for the fluentd image? Most of the time images can be set up so as to run as an arbitrary user, but a lot of the time they want to run as root even though they don't need to run as root. Requiring they be run as root when not necessary is generally regarded as a bad practice.

Comment: I have added the URL. The owner of the repo is Fluent itself. Can you please look at it and suggest if there is any workaround. I think the process maintains root access so as to install the gems for the required plugin.

Comment: Looking at what they do in the entry point script, there is no easy workaround. The whole way the application is set up in the image would need to be redone. Not that it is going to provide an immediate solution, guidelines for creating images that are portable and work with secure container deployment environments such as OpenShift and Kubernetes with RBAC, can be found at https://docs.openshift.org/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html

Comment: Ohh. Okay, thank you for the information. I will look into the link you provided. Thank you for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue in our Project. We solved this building a custom fluentd container based on the fluentd-onbuild image, which is designed to customize the base fluentd container. The Dockerfile is located here:

<s>https://github.com/Gepardec/Hogarama/blob/master/Fluentd/Dockerfile</s>

https://github.com/Gepardec/Hogarama/blob/0f91618c37493ef70eb5d83bcec3bd258edc29c3/Fluentd/Dockerfile

The project also contains openshift templates, which may contain some snippets you can use to adapt it to your needs:

<s>https://github.com/Gepardec/Hogarama/tree/master/Templates</s>

https://github.com/Gepardec/Hogarama/tree/0f91618c37493ef70eb5d83bcec3bd258edc29c3/Templates

Comment: Hey, I just tried using your Dockerfile. When the image runs, I get the following error - "config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="out_file: `/fluentd/log/docker.20180423.log` is not writable"

Comment: Any idea how I can get around this issue? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: I think this probably happens because the log dir is not writeable. We configured the logdir as volumeMount with a volumeClaim:
     persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: fluentd
and
      volumeMounts:
            - name: fluentd-log-volume
              mountPath: /

You can initilize it with emtpyDir if you don't want to keep the logs after the container stops. As the indentation in comments is not very good you can see a sample here: https://github.com/Gepardec/Hogarama/blob/master/Templates/dc/fluentd_dc.yaml

Comment: Ok awesome! That works, thank you so much for the help

Comment: Both these links are 404 now, is it possible to add their content into this answer?

Comment: I updated the links to the point where I know the info was correct.
So is this link from my previous comment:
https://github.com/Gepardec/Hogarama/tree/0f91618c37493ef70eb5d83bcec3bd258edc29c3/Templates/dc

But keep in mind that the commit is from 2018, so some things might not be up to date.